# Symbol 'vector' could not be resolved // Unable to find $PATH

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

Using Eclipse Kepler, Version: 4.3.1

CDT Version: 8.3.0

PTP Version: 7.0.5

On Fedora 19 
Kernel 3.14.27-100.fc19.x86_64
x86_64 GNU/Linux

From the source file -

```
#include "RegisterSet.h"
using namespace std;

RegisterSet::RegisterSet () {
    std::vector<long> defReg ();
}
```

From the header file -

```
#ifndef REGISTERSET_H_
#define REGISTERSET_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace std {

class RegisterSet {
public:
  RegisterSet();
  virtual ~RegisterSet();
  std::vector<long> defReg ();
};

} /* namespace std */

#endif /* REGISTERSET_H_ */
```

I was able to compile using vi and g++.
Problem starts when using Eclipse. I've tried setting -

```
Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > All options > " -std=c++0x"

GCC C++ Compiler > Dialect > language standard > C++11

GCC C++ Compiler > Includes > Include paths > /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/x86_64-redhat-linux

GCC C++ Compiler > Miscellaneous > Other flags > appended "-std=c++0x"

Current Tool Chain is Linux GCC

C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes for both GNU C and GNU C++ show /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/x86_64-redhat-linux

> Library Paths now shows /usr/lib64/ccache/
```

Under XL C/C++ Language Options, Allow vector type declarations is checked on.

```
Under C/C++ Build > XL C/C++ Compiler
I get "Compiler path does not exist on the local machine"
Compile Root Path is -
/usr/lib64/ccache/g++
Compiler version v8.0
```

Looks like I am also getting the following errors, I assume related to the compiler path issue above -

```
Unable to get $PATH.
Unable to find full path for "gcc"
Unable to get $PATH.
Unable to find full path for "g++"
```

Here is path -

```
$ which gcc
/usr/lib64/ccache/gcc
$ which g++
/usr/lib64/ccache/g++
$ which make
/usr/bin/make
```

Both /usr/lib64/ccache and /usr/bin are in path.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/libexec/lightdm:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/:.:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/<>/.local/bin:/home/<>/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/:.
```

Update:

Adding - /usr/lib64/ccache to XL C/C++ Compiler > Compiler Root Path, solves the "Compiler path does not exist on the local machine."

But still getting -

```
Unable to get $PATH.
Unable to find full path for "gcc"
```

And -

```
Semantic Error: 
Symbol 'vector' could not be resolved
```

So it seems like Eclipse is not correctly finding $PATH.

Thoughts on next steps?

Thanks

Comment: OT: Don't put your own classes into `namespace std`.  It's reserved for the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked -

1. Edit the project's environments settings (Properties/ C/C++ Build / Environment). If the PATH variable doesn't appear here or is not printed boldly, then cancel that dialog and edit them in Window / Preferences / C/C++ Build / Environment).
2. Make sure your PATH variable setting contains the string ':${PATH}'. It must have the curly braces around it! If the variable is already there and isn't resolved anyway, then get its value from your operating system and replace ${PATH} with that value.

Found here -
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/442732/

Originally from here -
http://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Hacking:Problems_and_solutions#Basic_tools_not_found_although_there

Console errors are gone, g++ and make are found by eclipse, binaries compile.
Vector resolves now too.

OT: I went ahead and removed the reference to namespace std from the class header file.  It is now only in the .cpp file.